# Круглые скобки в конце анонимной функции

Tags: golang, анонимная-функция

Подскажите пожалуйста зачем нужны круглые скобки, которые за фигурными, в самом конце кода? Я знаю, что эти скобки значат вызов на месте, но я все равно потом вызываю этот кусок кода через **fn()**.

Дайте пожалуйста ответ более развернуто. 5-ый час не могу въехать почему.

```
fn := func() func(int) int {
        count := 0
        return func(i int) int {
            count++
            return count * i
        }
    }()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ваша анонимная функция, которую вы вызываете пустыми скобками в конце вашего кода, возвращает другую функцию, которая присваивается переменной `fn`.

Вызов анонимной функции при её объявлении эквивалентен присвоению её в переменную и вызову из этой переменной.

Рассмотрим пример на основе вашего кода. Здесь мы присваиваем эту анонимную функцию переменной `makeFn` (обратите внимание, без круглых скобок после фигурных). Затем вызываем эту функцию, и результат присваиваем переменной `fn` (прямо как в вашем коде). Затем вызываем уже функцию `fn`, и результат записываем в переменную `r`. Для наглядности выведем типы этих переменных. Как видите, `makeFn` имеет тип функции, возвращающей функцию, `fn` имеет тип функции возвращающей целое число, а `r` имеет тип целого числа.

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    makeFn := func() func(int) int {
        count := 0
        return func(i int) int {
            count++
            return count * i
        }
    }
    fn := makeFn()
    r := fn(2)

    fmt.Printf("typeof(makeFn): %T\n", makeFn)
    fmt.Printf("typeof(fn): %T\n", fn)
    fmt.Printf("typeof(r): %T\n", r)
}
```

Вывод:

```
typeof(makeFn): func() func(int) int
typeof(fn): func(int) int
typeof(r): int
```

Может возникнуть вопрос: зачем нам нужна промежуточная функция (`makeFn`), если можно сразу записать нужную функцию в переменную `fn`? Конкретно в данном случае это необходимо для [замыкания (closure)](https://www.gobyexample.com.ru/closures). Переменная `count` оказывается в замыкании, и если мы вдруг захотим создать несколько экземпляров функции `fn`, то у каждого экземпляра будет своя независимая переменная `count`. Пример:

```
package main
 
import "fmt"
 
func main() {
    makeFn := func() func(int) int {
        count := 0
        return func(i int) int {
            count++
            return count * i
        }
    }
    fn1, fn2 := makeFn(), makeFn()
 
    fmt.Printf("fn1: ")
    for i := 1; i <= 3; i++ {
        fmt.Printf("%d ", fn1(i))
    }
    fmt.Println()
 
    fmt.Printf("fn2: ")
    for i := -1; i >= -3; i-- {
        fmt.Printf("%d ", fn2(i))
    }
    fmt.Println()
}
```

Вывод:

```
fn1: 1 4 9 
fn2: -1 -4 -9
```

Comment: Благодарю Вас за столь развернутый ответ!!!